# Add Additonal Clocks via Group Policy

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I'm trying to get as much as I can into GPOs so that new machines are as effortless as possible once joining the domain.

One thing I always do on a new machine is add a UTC and US clock.

[image: Additional clocks in Windows 7]

What's the best way to roll this out? Doesn't need to be mandatory, preferences are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to someone who looks like he'd know](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/winserverGP/thread/b5c0a3fe-2b24-4d8c-9b56-efa105edd0ab)...

> There is no Group Policy can show additional clock directly. But you still have two options to achieve it below:
>
> - Registry Group Policy Preference (GPP)
> - Logon script Group Policy
>
> For the detailed information, please refer to the following articles:
>
> [Registry Extension](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771589.aspx)
>
> [Add Additional Clock via Registry](http://www.leopartnik.com/blog/?p=388)
>
> [Use Startup, Shutdown, Logon, and Logoff Scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775970%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)
>
> [VBScript – Add additional clocks Vista and 7](http://www.leopartnik.com/blog/?p=411)

Combine first and second links for GPP approach, or third and fourth for GPO with script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it via powershell (London and New York). Works in Win7 and Win10.

```
IF (!(Test-Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\TimeDate\AdditionalClocks\')){
New-Item -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\' -Name "TimeDate" -ea 0
New-Item -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\TimeDate\' -Name "AdditionalClocks" -ea 0
New-Item -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\TimeDate\AdditionalClocks\' -Name "1" -ea 0
New-Item -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\TimeDate\AdditionalClocks\' -Name "2" -ea 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\TimeDate\AdditionalClocks\1' -Name "Enable" -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\TimeDate\AdditionalClocks\2' -Name "Enable" -Value 1
}
# London
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\TimeDate\AdditionalClocks\1' -Name "TzRegKeyName" -Value "GMT Standard Time"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\TimeDate\AdditionalClocks\1' -Name "DisplayName" -Value "London, UK"

# New York
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\TimeDate\AdditionalClocks\2' -Name "TzRegKeyName" -Value "Eastern Standard Time"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\TimeDate\AdditionalClocks\2' -Name "DisplayName" -Value "New York, USA"
```